# Why are number changing interactions inelastic?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, collision, relativity, scattering

Inelastic processes are those in which the kinetic energy of the initial particles and final particles are not the same. Is this true also for number changing processes such as pair creation or pair production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total energy is always conserved whilst kinetic energy is by definition total energy minus total rest mass energy. As such a collision is elastic if the sum of the rest masses doesn't change.

Pair production of say an $e^-e^+$ pair will create an extra $MeV$ or so of rest mass so it must be an inelastic process where kinetic energy decreases by that $MeV$. More generally any process $A+B\rightarrow C+D$ is inelastic if $m_A+m_B \neq m_C+m_D$, which is usually the case unless $A,B$ are the same particles as $C,D$.